# How to collect statistics on AWS Glue (catalog) tables in Spark-SQL

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

In our project we use `AWS Glue (catalog)` tables with location pointing to `parquet` data files stored on `S3`. Then we use `Spark-SQL` to query these tables to process the data and often fall into performance issues leading from lack of statistics (i think). I tried to collect statistics with the command 
`analyze table mytable compute stats` but it throws errors as - `Can not create path from empty string`.

I am completely clueless. My questions is how to alleviate this error so that statistics could be collected on these Glue tables properly which spark can then leverage for optimizing join operations ?

Comment: could you provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to do with your data and what's your cluster size and whether you are using Glue ETL or EMR.

Comment: @Harsh we don't use Glue ETL, we use EMR cluster. The data of the tables are stored on S3 as parquet files, on top which the Glue catalog tables are defined. We have Spark SQL which we use to do ETL. For e.g. we start with one of these tables as source table and keep on transforming them at multiple steps (temp views) to arrive at the required data.Since we use SparkSQL we frequently encounter performance issues. So wanted to know if there is a way to collect stats (like we do on Hive tables) on these source Glue tables  which could be leveraged by the SparkSQL Optimizer for better query plans